# Dependency parsing as graph

Tags: neo4j, nlp, spacy, graph-databases

I am using `spacy` for dependency parsing which I can visualize also .
Code snippet

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
displacy.serve(doc, style="dep")
```

Is it possible somehow I store this in any graph DB - say `neo4j`. If yes, then how? Also can this be done on paragraph level (multiple sentences).

My idea is to store multiple texts/paragraph into graph DB and apply graph algorithm for example `graph similarity`.

Does it make also sense to apply standard graph algorithm on dependency parsing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is the kind of thing Tomaz Bratanic does

you can check this out, for example: https://towardsdatascience.com/extract-knowledge-from-text-end-to-end-information-extraction-pipeline-with-spacy-and-neo4j-502b2b1e0754